# Python: Finding a combination of elements that matches a given sum

Tags: python, combinations

Suppose that I am given a sum S, and I am also given some elements of **fixed value** a, b, c and d. I am trying to write an algorithm that attempts to find the combination of **any length** (meaning it can just be a+b, or a+a+a...+a) of the fixed values that give the sum S.

**The sum and the fixed values are in binary and they contain 6 bits. This means the largest sum possible is actually 63 before overflow happens and we return to 0, and this also means that the fixed values can actually be bigger than the sum in question.**

```
def foo(array, c):
    v0 = int(convert(Ch[0]), 2) #These four lines here are simply converting my fixed values which are in an array into binary integers with a function, it is not important to the essence of the question.
    v1 = int(convert(Ch[1]), 2)
    v2 = int(convert(Ch[2]), 2)
    v3 = int(convert(Ch[3]), 2)
    rowlist = [v0, v1, v2, v3] #Create a list of the fixed values to iterate with a loop
    responsesum = 0
    challenger = int(convert(c), 2) #This is the Sum that we will match our combinations against, it is also a binary number
    print(f'The challenger is {challenger}')
    for i in range(4):
        if (rowlist[i] == challenger):
            return True
        for j in range(4):
            responsesum = rowlist[i] + rowlist[j]
            while responsesum >= 64: #This while loop attempts to get the 6bit value when overflow occurs (the combination has a value of more than 64, aka more than 7 bits)
                print(f'Overflow response is {responserow}')
                responsesum = responsesum - int(str(111111), 2) - int(str(1), 2)
            print(f'The sum is {responsesum}')

            if (responsesum == challenger):
                return True
            for k in range(4):
                responsesum = rowlist[i] + rowlist[j] + rowlist[k]
                while responsesum >= 64:
                    responsesum = responsesum - int(str(111111), 2) - int(str(1), 2)
                print(f'The sum is {responsesum}')
                if (responsesum == challenger):
                    return True
```

As you can see, this is a very inelegant piece of code, and in fact, I have to basically **manually decide the length of the combination by continuing to add for loops when I am unable to find the combination for given sum.**

**Is there a way to elegantly implement this (Such that perhaps the algorithm decides to add a new for loop and increase the combination length by 1 whenever there is no solution?)**

Comment: change the first five lines of your code to `rowlist = [int(convert(Ch[i]), 2) for i in range (4)]`

Comment: Is there some sort of scoring on the answer you come up with?  Like, is finding an answer that uses fewer terms better than one that uses more?  Or is the best one the answer that takes the fewest number of tries?  Do you have any prior knowledge of the ranges of values that the inputs might take?

Comment: @Steve There are no such restrictions. I just need to implement this algorithm in anyway possible. Of course if theres a good way to do it, I prefer to learn that, but anything is fine

Comment: Why is this so complicated: `while responsesum >= 64:   responsesum = responsesum - int(str(111111), 2) - int(str(1), 2)`?  Can't this just be `while responsesum >= 64:   response -= 64` or better yet `responsesum = responsesum % 64`?

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the headsup, that is much more readable